# System.out.println("Serializable: " + arrayList instanceof Serializable) is not printing 'Serializable' word

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I tried to execute following simple code. System.out.println() is not printing word 'Serializable:'.
Output is **true**.

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.println("Serializable: " + arrayList instanceof Serializable);
```

Can anyone expain why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `("Serializable: " + arrayList) instanceof Serializable` vs. `"Serializable: " + (arrayList instanceof Serializable)`

Comment: Correct.. Now I understood. Its because of operator precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing out a bracket. You should be writing like this :

```
System.out.println("Serializable: " + (arrayList instanceof Serializable))
```

Comment: Because of Operator precedence.. :)